# 2D from 3D animation/graphics

Tags: animation, swift, graphics, 3d, 2d

I am sorry if it's a duplicate, but most of questions ask an opposite thing: 3D from 2D or sometimes they ask for a tool '2D from 3D' or: what to choose 2D or 3D. My case is different, I don't want any software/tool(s), I have already chosen the dimensions and I want 2D from 3D. Also I would like to give it a try writing myself, that's why I don't want any software.

I do understand that it will be a long term project, especially for such an amateur as me, but I find it interesting, that's why I want to attempt this task.

I will probably take 3D objects from the Xcode's Scene Kit and I would like to write a code, which will convert them into 2D.

I don't know what to start from and what to read. So any help will be very much appreciated. Also if there are some code examples (no matter which language) it will be awesome, because it's good to see how to assemble things/code etc.

//Also, please, have a look at the tags. I am not quite sure whether I choose them correctly. I will add Swift just in case. Because in my case it will be Swift, actually. However, the question is sort of general, so some people who won't use Swift may probably find prospective answers useful as well.

Comment: This question is too broad to be answered here. As you noted yourself, the problem has many faces and aspects, and it would take too much space to explain it all here. Asking for books, tutorials and references is on the other hand off-topic here. I suggest you rephrase that a bit and take into GameDev.SE

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Have looked through the GameDev.SE. Seems they won't accept a question 'what to get started from' as well((